# KB4012212 "Update not applicable"

Tags: windows-7

Im installing the KB4012212 patch to a windows 7 machine, running Windows 7 Premium 32-bit. I have the correct patch file, but when I run the patch, i get the Windows Stand Alone Installer error:

```
"The update is not applicable to your computer"
```

I think it has something to do with lacking the pre requisite updates that precede the patch, but cannot find any information on this to confirm. I have ran the Windows updater, and patches have been installed, but none that tackle the MS17-010 Wanacry bug.

Any information will be greatly recieved.

Comment: Do you have KB4012215 installed on your system instead? If so, KB4012212 will not be applicable.

Comment: Nope, I checked the list that microsoft released of the patches that cover the MS17-010 hole, but none appear on the list of installed updates on the machine.

Comment: Try to install first KB2919442 -> KB2919355 -> kb4012213.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, and assistance. I got it to work by manually installing SP1, first then patch KB4012212.